# Move row to Archive tab when the letter "a" is entered in a specified column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have made a collective TODO list, and it proved to be quite useful. Done tasks should be moved from time to time to the "archive" Tab, which I would like to do by entering the value "a" in column G.

I tried it like so:

```
var sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo = "archive";
var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo);
var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);

sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).moveTo(targetRange);
sheet.deleteRow(range.getRow());
```

that did work (in another way) in another script, but not in this one:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AveLEDuTZv0vdGh6LXNleFpBa2hYNmx0aDVKblNGaVE&usp=sharing

Maybe there is some conflict? Any help?

Thanks, Tobias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function will move data from 'TODO List' to 'archive'.
The code that you wrote to too big, I believe that you are doing something more with that code. But I have only coded to move data from TODO List to archive tab if someone put 'a' in column 7. I have added this code to your spreadsheet and you can test it from there.

```
function AneesHameed(e)
{
  var SourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('TODO List');
  var DestSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('archive');
  var Column = e.range.getColumn();
  var ChangeHappendAt = e.source.getActiveSheet().getName();
  var Row = e.range.getRow();
  if(ChangeHappendAt == "TODO List" && Column == 7 && Row > 3 && e.value == "a")
  {
    var LastRow = DestSheet.getLastRow()+1;
    DestSheet.getRange(LastRow, 1, 1, 10).setValues(SourceSheet.getRange(Row, 1, 1, 10).getValues());
    SourceSheet.getRange(Row, 1, 1, 10).clearContent();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting the error, "ss is not defined", which comes from this line of code.

```
var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo);
```

The line of code that would have defined ss is commented out:  Line 28

```
//var ss = e.source.getActiveSheet();
```

If you open up the **Execution Transcript** under the **View** menu after running the code, you should see an error in the last line of the Log.

> [14-09-17 01:45:14:123 CEST] Ausführung fehlgeschlagen:
>   ReferenceError: "ss" ist nicht definiert. (line 82, file "timestamp")
>   (0.156 Sekunden Laufzeit insgesamt)

Comment: allright, I removed the commenting. still the script is doing nothing when i insert an a in collumn G. (what it should do, is move that row to the archive tab)