# Recording value of a cell which changes monthly

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, scripting

Here's what I am trying to accomplish but failed so far.

Say the summed value of a cell in A1 changes every day. In column c2 I have the date 01/02/2020, in c3 02/02/2020 and so on, now what I want to do in d2,d3... is keep a record of the value of A1 if today's date matches the value of c2.

Does anyone know how this can be achieved?

Comment: possible only with script

Comment: that was what i thougth. Could you give me some guidelines to follow? thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-apps-script%5D+archive

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25885124/5632629 if you modify the "=a" part for "non-empty"

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
function createTrigger() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('checkA1').timeBased().atHour(6).everyDays(1).create();
}

function checkA1() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var A1=sh.getRange(1,1).getValue();
  var tds=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"MM/dd/yyyy");
  var dtA=sh.getRange(2,3,sh.getLastRow()-1,1).getValues().map(function(r,i){return r[0];}).filter(function(e){return e;});
  dtA.forEach(function(dt,i){if(tds==Utilities.formatDate(new Date(dt),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"MM/dd/yyyy")){sh.getRange(i+2,4).setValue(A1);}});
}
```